# Display const in template with Angular 4 / ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have constants declared in the constructor in my .ts file. I'd like to display their value in the template.

Is it good practices?

**EDIT:**

```
import {Component, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {MemoryEditPage} from "../memory-edit/memory-edit";


@Component({
    selector: 'page-memory-list',
    templateUrl: 'memory-list.html',
})
export class MemoryListPage implements OnInit {

    @Output() k_user: string;
    @Output() type: MemoryType = MemoryType.memories;


    constructor(
        private auth: AuthService,
        public navCtrl: NavController,
    ) {
        const monthNames = ['Janvier','Février','Mars','Avil','Mai','Juin','Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre'];
        const thisMonth = monthNames[(new Date()).getMonth()];
        const dayNames = ['Lun','Mar','Mer','Jeu','Ven','Sam','Dim'];
        const thisDay = dayNames[(new Date()).getDay() - 1];
        const thisDate = (new Date()).getDate();

        this.thisDay = thisDay;
        this.thisDate = thisDate;
        this.thisMonth = thisMonth;

    }


}
```

Template:

```
<ion-label no-margin text-uppercase color="white">{{thisMonth}}</ion-label>
```

Comment: Well, it won't work, so I guess we can say it's not good practice. The view doesn't have access to local variables of the constructor. They're **local** variables.

Comment: sorry I forgot a few lines and my code was not functional. My question is still there: is this best practices to put variables with `this.` in the constructor or should I put them elsewhere?

Comment: The monthNames and dayNames don't need to be recreated every time the constructor is invoked. Just store them in a constant, outside of the class. The other local variables are useless. Just initialize the fields directly. Don't recreate a new Date() for each of them: create it once. And note that Angular already have ways to get month and day names.

Comment: Ok thanks for your comment. Can you point me to "Angular's ways to get month and day names." ?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/getLocaleMonthNames, https://angular.io/api/common/getLocaleDayNames, https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Answer (score 0):

It can't be considered as a practice in the first place as you can't do it. You can only access a Component's (`public`) Properties and methods in your Component's Template.

You'll have to define a property on your Component for that.

```
...
@Component({...})
export class MemoryListPage implements OnInit {

    ...
    thisMonth;

    constructor(...) {
        ...
        const thisMonth = monthNames[(new Date()).getMonth()];
        this.thisMonth = thisMonth;
        ...
    }
}
```

And then use it in your template:

```
<ion-label 
  no-margin 
  text-uppercase 
  color="white">
  {{thisMonth}}
</ion-label>
```

**UPDATE:**

Answering your updated question, it's not really a good practice to write any instantiation logic in the `constructor`. It should be written in `ngOnInit`. Even the [**Angular's Official Docs**](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#oninit) vouch for this:

> Experienced developers agree that components should be cheap and safe to construct.
>
> Misko Hevery, Angular team lead, [**explains why**](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/) you should avoid complex constructor logic.